# returning results from multiple dictionaries in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm learning Python (3.6) to work with API data returned in JSON (which is also new to me).  The API call returns 26 files which comprise the entirety of our data set - Page 1 of 26, Page 2 of 26 etc.

I'm able to iterate through a single dictionary to get the required parsed results but need to return results from all dictionaries.  Tried merging them using suggestions from here, but unsuccessfully.  The following code only returns results from the last dictionary:

`mkt = {**mkt1, **mkt2}`

The parsing script is:

```
for prop in mkt["properties"]:
    for space in mkt["properties"][0 - len(mkt)]["spaces"]:
        try:
            if prop["name"][1:8] == "TESTING":
                del prop
            else:
                print(prop["name"][0:5], prop["name"][6:], space["floor"]["name"], space["suite"])
        except:
            pass
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just to be clear do you mean you have 26 dictionaries, each of which contains further dictionaries (mimicking the JSON structure)? It'd probably help if you posted a small sample of the data structure you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have all dictionaries in a list of other data structure and that the parsing code works for a single dictionary.

You can wrap the code in a function and then call the function using a `for` loop for each dictionary.

I should help to make your code a little more readable.

```
def iter_dict(mkt):
""" 
Takes a dictionary as an argument for parsing information
"""

    for prop in mkt["properties"]:
        for space in mkt["properties"][0 - len(mkt)]["spaces"]:
            try:
                if prop["name"][1:8] == "TESTING":
                    del prop
                else:
                    print(prop["name"][0:5], prop["name"][6:], space["floor"]["name"], space["suite"])
            except:
                pass

for dictionary in dict_list:
    iter_dict(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks johnashu!

Your solution worked for me!

To clarify for any people just starting out, we created a list of dictionaries like so:

`mkt = [mkt1, mkt2, mkt3...mkt26]`

Once we had the list of dictionaries, the code block was wrapped in code to iterate through all dictionaries, as shown by johnashu.

The last statement was updated to reference the list of dictionaries:

```
for dictionary in mkt:    
    iter_dict(dictionary)
```

Comment: This should be a (brief) comment on the accepted answer, not a separate answer. The clarification of what the answer is actually solving should be in the question itself.